# linux alive message

Tags: linux

I'm trying to periodically check out if several linux machines are alive.

My idea is to have a main computer that receives a periodic message from every machine, so if any of them stops messaging, the main one will know something's going wrong with that particular equipment.

I want to make it as "lite" as possible, I mean, using the less data transmission possible, because some of the machines I want to look after are placed on installation with a not so good internet connection. So, if it's possible, I'll prefer not to use email or ftp.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thought I had too, Oded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a dedicated piece of software for monitoring your infrastructure. Inventing something from scratch will probably take longer and be much less powerful than such a product. [nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) for example is something that is commonly used for this purpose.

Comment: for a simple heart-beat nagios is an overkill, but if you want to monitor cpu, processes, free disk space etc it's quite nice. alerting is very nice, the way you can structure your nodes, services and dependencies is brilliant.

Comment: In the end I installed Nagios. There are several helpful tutorials. The only problem I had was with the email sending. I finally modified the sending command line to make it work properly, but it was easy as it's all file's based.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could connect to the main machine on a specific port and keep sending one byte periodically. Is that "lite" enough? :)